# split scp of backup files to different smb shares based on date

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I backup files to Tar files once a day and grab from our Ubuntu servers using a backup shell script and put them in a share.  We only have 5TB shares but can have several.

At the moment we need more as we backup 30 days worth of Tar files.

I need a method where the first 10 days go to share one, next ten to share tow, next 11 to share three

Currently each Server VM runs the following script to backup and tar folders and place then in another folder ready to be grabbed by the backup server

```
!/bin/bash

appname=myapp.com

dbname=mydb

dbuser=myDBuser

dbpass=MyDBpass

datestamp=`date +%d%m%y`

rm -f /var/mybackupTars/* > /dev/null 2>&1

mysqldump -u$dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > /var/mybackups/$dbname-$datestamp.sql && gzip /var/mybackupss/$dbname-$datestamp.sql

tar -zcf /var/mybackups/myapp-$datestamp.tar.gz /var/www/myapp > /dev/null 2>&1

tar -zcf /var/mydirectory/myapp-$datestamp.tar.gz /var/www/html/myapp > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I then grab the backups using a script on the backup server and put them in a share

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Generate a list of myapps to grab
df|grep myappbackups|awk -F/ '{ print $NF }'>/tmp/myapplistlistsmb

# Get each app in turn

for APPNAME in `cat /tmp/applistsmb`
do
        cd /srv/myappbackups/$APPNAME
        scp $APPNAME:* .
done
```

I know this is a tough one but I really need 3 shares with ten days worth in each share

I do not anticipate the backup script changing on each server VM that backs up to itself

Only maybe the grabber script that puts the dated backups in the share on the backup server

Or am I wrong??

Any help would be great

Comment: I am thinking now as I run a delete cron on the backup server, I might be able to pass all backup tar files to each share and the delete from each share based on dates each day. this would create a fair bit of network traffic. my delete cron is find /srv/mybackups/* -maxdepth 1 -mtime +30 -type f -delete
Is there a way of deleting different sets of dates, so i run three crons to delete from each share but deleting the first 20 days from the 3rd share, the middle 20 days from 2nd share and last 20 days from the first share:)

Comment: Instead of pulling, if you can push your data from VM.s then i think you can change to the destination backup server every 10 days using some simple logic (like date % 10 for eg.,)

Comment: I cannot do that as I have taken over this and there are many other servers working in the same way. I think I need to put all files on all three shares and then run some crons to delete the right files so I have the first 10 on share 1, next 10 on share two ect. - thanks